# Python and BeautifulSoup encoding issue

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup, xbmc

I'm web scraping this url : http://www.rajtamil.com/category/vijay-tv-shows/

Getting stuck with this error:

```
    movTitle = str(link['title'])
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's my code snippet

```
    rajTamilurl='http://www.rajtamil.com/category/vijay-tv-shows/'
    req = urllib2.Request(rajTamilurl)
    req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3) Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    link=response.read()
    response.close()

    #Here's what i've tried so far
    #link=link.decode('utf-8')
    #link=link.encode('utf-8','ignore')
    #link=link.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(link, from_encoding="utf-8")
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(link.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
    #soup = BeautifulSoup(link, 'html5lib')
    #print soup.prettify()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(link)
    for eachItem in soup.findAll('li'):
        for coveritem in eachItem.findAll("div", { "class":"cover" }):
            links = coveritem.find_all('a')
            for link in links:
                print link['title']
                movTitle = str(link['title'])
```

Any pointers ?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to `str`? It should be already `unicode` which is a better way to process string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is small part of a bigger piece of code which is filled with str's all the way(So are the lib's that i'm importing). Will be a pain in the bottom to de-str those, plus i'm not very comfortable with char encodings....

Comment: Did you have a `# coding: utf-8` line at the beginning of your script?

Comment: nope. Did not have that at the beginning of the script. Rest of the code is available here for referance : http://pastebin.com/cW7HF8Va

Comment: @gbzygil `# coding: utf-8` is not the problem here, take a look at the answer.

Comment: *"i'm not very comfortable with char encodings.."* -- you can fix it. Most of what you need to know when working with text is: 1. Decode early 2. Unicode everywhere 3. Encode late. That's it. [Explain it like I'm five: Python and Unicode?](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1g62eh/explain_it_like_im_five_python_and_unicode/)

Comment: I'll also recommend Joel's http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. It is also a very pleasant reading.

Answer (score 2):

Although I strongly don't recommend to work with `str`, I understand you have some constrains. Try changing this line:

```
movTitle = str(link['title'])
```

with this one:

```
movTitle = link['title'].encode('utf8')
```

When you `encode` an `unicode` string, you get its respective encoded `str` version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why do you thing `utf8` is appropriate here? We don't know what character encoding or even *multiple* character encodings are used by other parts of the code. Using bytestrings in this case leads to an eventual silent data corruption.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I went to the web page and checked that's why I suggested. I know about that but the OP is decided to work with `str` :( I'm just trying to explain somehow the error to him.

Comment: The only part of the code that needs to know and uses the html source character encoding is `BeautifulSoup()`. `link['title']` is a Unicode string (no associated character encoding at this step). How other parts of the code would know about the the html source character encoding?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know my answer ain't brilliant. I just tried to meet the OP's expectations. I asked all these before answering and believe me, I know what you're trying to tell me. If you read the comments the first one was _why convert to str_?